# Passing back "NaN`" and "Inf`" to C via MathLink

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp

In the "usual" `double` representation of floating point numbers in C there is a `NaN` and an `Inf` value.  (I'm saying usual because I am not deeply familiar with the various floating point formats that are used in practice.  Please correct me when necessary.)

These special values [can be sent back to Mathematica via MathLink](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/397/correct-way-to-handle-mysterious-nan-result-from-mathlink-function), and they will display as `` Nan` `` and `` Inf` ``.  `NumberQ` returns true on them.

**Short version:** How can these special values be created in Mathematica and sent back to C?  (But please see the long version)

**Long version:**

Mathematica represents these special cases as `Infinity`, `-Infinity`, `ComplexInfinity`, and `Indeterminate`.  These symbols can be sent back through MathLink, and handled on the C but, but I'd prefer not to do this because: 1. It's complicated.  2. It's slow.  I'd have to use `MLPutReal64*` functions to make the packed array case fast anyway.  So I'd prefer to somehow be able to use `MLPutReal64*` to send NaN and Inf as well.

How can we persuade `MLPutReal64` to handle these values?  We'd have to create the same thing that `MLGetReal64` returns for NaNs, and send that.  It seems there's no built-in way to create these in Mathematica, but I can always write a MathLink-based function that returns them and then keep them as constants in Mathematica.  I tried this and I verified that it works on OS X 64 bit.

**The big question is: is it safe to do this?  Am I going to run into problems?  Is the program going to be portable among the main platforms (Win/Lin/OSX, both 32 and 64 bit)?**

To make the question completely clear, I'd like to do something like this:

```
numbers = {1., 100., 100000., Infinity}

inf = getInf[] (* MathLink-based function that returns "Inf` " *)

sendToC[ numbers /. Infinity -> inf ]
```

(If anyone is interested, it seems that `` Developer`PackedArrayQ@Developer`ToPackedArray[{1., 2., 3., 4., inf}] `` returns `True`.  Also a big warning for those who'd think of doing calculations with these special values in Mathematica: don't!! Nearly all operations on them, even pattern matching, are broken and return nonsense results.  E.g. `` MatchQ[Inf`, NaN`] === True ``, `` Inf` + 1 === 1 ``, etc.)

**Additionally:**

[Here's a relevant discussion of the issue on MathGroup by John Fultz.](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2011/Sep/msg00326.html)  There are two suggestions in that thread (other than sending symbols directly): 1. Designating certain Mathematica-representable floating point values to denote NaN and Inf.  2. Explicitly passing the integer indices of NaNs and Infs in the array.  But if the way I described above works, I'd much rather just use that, as it's so much simpler.

Comment: FWIW, I did not yet implement sending such quantities to R via `RLink`, partly intentionally: can you envision any meaningful application of them on the "other side"?

Comment: @Leonid One (theoretical!) application is some kind of hybrid R/Mathematica code which first calls an R functions, takes the result, calls a (simple) Mathematica function on it, then calls a second R function on the output.  If the first R function returned an `inf`, it'll break the hybrid program, even if it wouldn't break an R-only program.  I.e. `runf2@rfun1[data]`  would not work in Mathematica but `rfun2(rfun1(data))` would work in R.  Admittedly, it's not a big deal.

Comment: But, the point is, we do support the transfer of these quantities from R to Mathematica. So, the recipe so far is simple: just don't send them back to R. I have a hard time coming up with something meaningful that R can do with those quantities if it receives them from Mathematica. The reverse is not necessariy true due to symbolic nature of Mathematica.

Comment: We decided to not include the reverse transfer for these quantites for the first version of RLink. If we get some feedback requesting it, we'll implement it in the future versions.

Comment: @Leonid I completely agree that it's not an important point.  But these issues do come up when one is trying to make a link this this (I just verified that `REvaluate["Inf"]` is `{Infinity}` and not ``{Inf`}``, so you thought about it too, and RLink handles it correctly), and this is what prompted my question. My question was: is it safe to use the solution I described?  If yes, why not use it?  It's so simple.  If not, then I agree that implementing a more complex solution is not worth the trouble at this stage.

Comment: Sure - my comments were intended to be rather tangential to your question, since I don't know the answer to it.I seem to remember playing with these (``Inf` ``etc) long time ago, and back then I decided to not use them, but I don't remember the reason alas.

Comment: Interesting that ``Developer`PackedArrayQ`` returns true in that case. An alternative, that may be safer is to use [this guy's suggestion](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2011/Sep/msg00427.html) (same thread, just deeper). More data is required to pass, but not necessarily that much.

Comment: @rcollyer Yes, that's point (2.) under "Additionally".. I'm leaning towards that as well, but that solution is more complicated, so I thought I'd ask about this one first.

Comment: @Szabolcs I guess I should have read that a little closer ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I decided that it is not worth risking breakage by doing this.  It is possible to create values displayed as `` Inf` `` and `` NaN` `` in Mathematica in hackish ways (returning them through MathLink), but these don't behave very well.  For example, in v9 on OS X, `` 1 + Inf` == 1 ``; `` MatchQ[NaN`, -Inf`] === True `` but `` NaN` == -Inf` `` is `False`.

As several people have suggested, I decided on passing the integer indices of where each of `Indeterminate`, `Infinity` and `-Infinity` are located, for *both* directions of transfer through MathLink.  This is more work, but it's safe.

I hope this will be of help to someone.