# Machine precision infinity

Tags: machine-precision, librarylink, numerical-value

Is it possible to obtain the machine precision (double) version of `Infinity`? This is useful when using `LibraryLink` and C functions that accept doubles: passing `Infinity` raises a type error, because `Infinity` is a symbol.

Comment: something like `$MaxMachineNumber`?

Comment: @chuy: $MaxMachineNumber is the largest finite number the machine's native floating point type can represent. But IEEE floating point numbers can also represent plus and minus infinity. I guess he means those.

Comment: @nikie that makes sense

Comment: I think that it is not possible. It's possible to get these special floating point values into Mathematica, but they'll cause all sorts of problems and it's not possible to do reliable operations on them.  Things fail randomly.  My opinion is that it's not worth the risk to push it.  More info here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19026/passing-back-nan-and-inf-to-c-via-mathlink

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible, and safe, provided that you do it inside the VM and not in top-level code. ([Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs)'s [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19026/passing-back-nan-and-inf-to-c-via-mathlink) provides the proof that dealing with these at top level is not safe; the values are not handled even slightly correctly.) This is reasonable to do for `LibraryFunction`s, because they can be called efficiently from the VM.

First we need a `LibraryFunction` that can distinguish a floating-point infinity:

```
infinityQ = With[{$MaxMachineNumber = $MaxMachineNumber},
   Compile[
    {{x, _Real, 0}}, If[x > $MaxMachineNumber, True, False],
    CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ]
  ];

libfuncinfinityQ = Last[infinityQ]
(* -> LibraryFunction[<>, compiledFunction0, {{Real, 0, Constant}}, True|False] *)
```

Now we test it:

```
With[{
   $MaxMachineNumber = $MaxMachineNumber,
   $MachineEpsilon = $MachineEpsilon
  },
 Compile[{},
   libfuncinfinityQ[(1 + $MachineEpsilon) $MaxMachineNumber (* makes an infinity *)]
 ][]
]
(* -> True *)
```

Note that this was done just using the VM, without producing another `LibraryFunction`. (That is, the call comes from *Mathematica*, not compiled C code.)

For completeness:

```
libfuncinfinityQ[$MaxMachineNumber]
(* -> False *)
```

Note that even though you can work with infinite or not-a-number values normally inside the VM, it is not possible to pass them between there and the top level (to do so produces an error). **However**, trying to pass these same values back out of a `LibraryFunction` causes them to be substituted with `DirectedInfinity[+1|-1]` (but *not* `ComplexInfinity`, which does not exist in IEEE754) and `Indeterminate`, which is (hopefully) not as problematic.

#### Cautionary note

As I mentioned [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19179/what-is-the-maximum-real-value-for-compile/19185#19185), arithmetic operations in the VM do not treat not-a-number values as they should be treated according to IEEE754. One should beware of similar pitfalls concerning the infinities; in particular, comparing them with other values could lead to problems. On the other hand, it is safe to produce these values, so if one just needs them for the purposes of supplying them as arguments to other functions, then these arithmetic issues may never arise.