# Remove list elements that contain NaN Symbol

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a long list of lists ...similar to `g = {{1,2,3},{4,2,7}, .....{1.2,9}}`.

Occasionally, `g` contains elements like `{3,5, NaN}`, that include the `NaN` symbol.

I would like to replace `g` with a new list, say `gg`, in which all of the offensive list elements (lists including the `NaN` symbol) have been removed.

Can someone show me how I can do this?

Background:
I am doing some 2D optical waveguide modeling using COMSOL, and I export postprocessing data over a predefined grid. For example, {x,y,z} gives the (x,y) position in the waveguide, and z might be one component of the electric field (which is represented by a complex number). The NaN values come up because COMSOL defines the field outside the WG structure as undefined and some grid positions are just outside the WG structure; those coordinates have NaN for their z-element. So I think it is fine to simply drop those list elements from consideration.

Comment: If you have only integers `Cases[{3, 5, NaN}, _Integer]` would work. Same with `Real` of course. Or if you work on g: `gg =
Cases[#, _Real | _Integer] & /@ g`

Comment: This might get complicated and it all depends on how you got these `NaN`s in the first place.  Can you update your question and explain how the NaNs got in your list?  *They might or might not be symbols.*  Mathematica itself should never ever give you any NaNs, so usually they appear only if you interface with external programs/libraries through MathLink/LibraryLink.

Comment: There's some info on this [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19026/12).  Generally the best thing to do is try not to get NaNs into Mathematica at all as Mathematica can't reliably handle them.

Comment: @Szabolcs wouldn't a `Cases` be sufficient in all cases?

Comment: @Öskå Unfortunately, no, or at least not if you want a guarantee that nothing will be unexpectedly wrong, and that it will work in all versions and all platforms.  If the OP imported these lists form a text file, and this `NaN` he is referring to is a symbol or a string, then yes.  However, if it is a true floating point `NaN`, i.e. a special floating point value, then Mathematica simply doesn't support it and [pattern matching is not reliable with it](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19560/12).

Comment: @Öskå Another problem is that you can't type a NaN directly into Mathematica---as I said it gives you no way to directly generate these values unless you inject them through a low-level API like MathLink/LibraryLink.  They can be manipulated only if you store them into a variable, but not typed directly as input.  So if the OP encountered a true floating point NaN, then none of the answers below will work because they all try to replace a `NaN` *symbol*.  **John**--it's not possible to answer your question unless you explain where these NaNs came from.

Comment: @Szabolcs thanks for taking the time to explain :)

Comment: I am doing some 2D optical waveguide modeling using COMSOL, and I export postprocessing data over a predefined grid. For example, {x,y,z} gives the (x,y) position in the waveguide, and z might be one component of the electric field (which is represented by a complex number). The NaN values come up because COMSOL defines the field outside the WG structure as undefined and some grid positions are just outside the WG structure; those coordinates have NaN for their z-element. So I think it is fine to simply drop those list elements from consideration.

Comment: @John Thanks for the additional details, but what I need to know is not why, but how do you get those NaNs into Mathematica? Do you use Import to read them from a file? If yes, what type of file? We need to know if those NaNs are symbols, strings, or floating point numbers to be able to give you a usable answer.

Comment: @Szabolcs It's the dreaded `NaN` vs. `NaN'`. It's a little infuriating. Especially when you wrap one in `Rationalize` and see all the different results.

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of the structure of g, nested lists etc...

```
gg = g /. NaN->Sequence[];
```

This replaces all NaNs with an empty Sequence that collapses to nothing.

Comment: Note: "NaN"->Sequence[] would work. NaN is meant as a string.