# Calculating the mean of a list with NaN values

Tags: list-manipulation

```
list={1,2,3,NaN,2}
```

I'd like to calculate the mean of this list, ignoring the `NaN`.
Answer should be `2` if the `NaN` is ignored.
Seems like this should be crazy simple, but I haven't seen anything reasonable.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is "NaN" here?  How did it get into your list in the first place?

Comment: OK - original list was list={1,2,3,0,2}. I'd like to ignore all of the values of zero in this case. NaN is the shortcut for "NotANumber". I tried replacing the zero with a NaN, but Mathematica doesn't like that.

Comment: Matlab handles it this way: A = [1 0 0 1 NaN 1 NaN 0];
M = mean(A,'omitnan')

Comment: You did not answer my question. There is no standard symbol called `NaN` in Mathematica.  Where did this list come from?  Did you type it in?  Was it returned by a library?  Please edit your question and make this clear.

Comment: Yes, I typed it in.

Comment: This is called `Indeterminate` in Mathematica, not `NaN`.  Corey's answer is correct then (except don't use `NaN`).

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ComputerArithmetic/ref/NaN.html

Comment: That is something entirely different, provided by a package. It is not a built-in symbol.

Comment: "Yes, I typed it in."  This is like the old Henny Youngman joke:  "Doc, it hurts when I do this."  Doc's response:  "Don't do that!"

Comment: From that reference on `NaN`:  To use NaN, you first need to load the Computer Arithmetic Package using Needs["ComputerArithmetic`"].  Are you using the ComputerArithmetic package?

Comment: OK, this seems to work for a list, but not a matrix. I'll have to reask the question, this time without the NaN

Comment: If it's just the mean of all of the non-NaN numbers in a matrix, then throw in a `Flatten` to any of the solutions below.

Comment: Let me just clarify why your question has caused such confusion. *Mathematica* has a rather unique model of arithmetic and departs from IEEE754 in many important respects. In particular, if you somehow manage to get an actual IEEE754 NaN value into the system, it will give extreme difficulties to deal with it in any consistent and useful way. This is what makes people nervous on seeing your question. For some value that has a meaning like that of NaN but is not an IEEE754 NaN, you can just use the officially sanctioned and supported value of `Indeterminate`.

Comment: ...or, you can use the eminently more readable `Missing[]` if you're uncomfortable with `Indeterminate`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your `NaN` comes from an external program and is just some symbol, then

```
Mean @ Select[list, # =!= NaN &]
```

or

```
list /. NaN -> Nothing // Mean
```

> 2

Comment: This assumes that OP is talking about a plain old symbol that happens to be called `NaN` (that he maybe typed in).  This is likely the case. But there are dangerous things that look like "NaN" in Mathematica: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19026/12  Even if he did type it in, he should be aware that in Mathematica, `NaN` has no special meaning the same way `Indeterminate` does.

Comment: Good to know about this new thing of `Nothing`.

Answer (score 10):

Well, it is a bit more nuanced in my opinion. It seems like the right functionality is to actually do keep track of the illegal entries in the system, similar to keeping missing variables for the statistical analysis in other packages. If that's the case, the more appropriate way is to actually code them with [`Missing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Missing.html). Then the computation can be done ignoring such entries, but the list would still retain the structure of the original data and can always be used for any analysis that do care about missing observations.

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 3, 5};
listnothing = list /. {0 -> Nothing};
listmissing = list /. {0 -> Missing["Not A Number"]};
Mean[listnothing]
Mean[DeleteMissing[listmissing]]
```

> `8/3`
>
> `8/3`

So far so good, but compare what happens if you want to plot the lists:

```
Row[MapThread[
  ListLinePlot[#, PlotLabel -> Style[#2, Bold, 15], 
    ImageSize -> Medium] &, 
    {{list, listnothing, listmissing}, 
    {"Original List", "List with Nothing", "List with Missing"}}]]
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Not only the shape is wrong (it show the connection between points that doesn't exist), but also the number of observations is wrong in the case of [`Nothing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nothing.html), so the more appropriate way for the data processing is to use [`Missing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Missing.html).

Answer (score 6):

```
Mean@Cases[{1, 2, 3, NaN, 2}, Except[NaN]]
(* 2 *)

Mean@DeleteCases[{1, 2, 3, NaN, 2}, NaN]
(* 2 *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Solve[Mean[{2, nan, 1, 4}] == nan]
```

Or

```
Solve[Mean[list] == nan]
```