# Wha't the meaning of NaN in the descriptor of ImageKeypoints

Tags: bugs, image-processing, machine-learning

**Bug introduced in 10.3 or earlier and persisting through 11.3**

---

```
obj = ResourceObject["CIFAR-10"];
trainingData = ResourceData[obj, "TrainingData"];
imgTest = trainingData[[29562]][[1]]
ImageKeypoints[ImageResize[imgTest, 256], "Descriptor"][[112]]
```

Since this causes a bug of my post codes[ClusteringCompoment of codebook]...I wonder is this a bug of ImageKeypoint or it's a feature?

Background:
the bag of words example in the HelpPage of ImageKeypoint.

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Standard bugs header](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1610/121)?  Also [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tags/bugs/info).

Comment: I don't see the bug in 10.0.2, but in that version the output is quite different. I don't have 10.1 and 10.2.

Comment: @Szabolcs I've edited to Mma 11.3

Comment: I have actually tested 10.3 and several newer versions, up to 11.3 and it was present in all of them.

Answer (score 9):

I believe this is a bug. [`` NaN` `` is not a value that can be safely computed with.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19560/12)  It really should not arise when using normal documented functions.  Please report this to support.