# Does NumericArray always maintain data unmodified?

Tags: binary, numeric-array

Suppose that we create a [`NumericArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NumericArray.html) using a LibraryLink function, then pass this to another one. Is NumericArray guaranteed to maintain the binary data as it was created, without any modifications?

One might think that there is no practical difference between a `Real64` NumericArray and a packed array of reals. Actually, there are some values that are not quite compatible with the latter, such as various kinds of NaNs, or ±infinity. These values can't be handled by Mathematica because Mathematica does not conform to IEEE 754. They can be returned from a LibraryLink function, but [they often lead to inconsistent behaviour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19026/12).

Are such values safe in a NumericArray of Real64 type? I'd hope to be able to trust NumericArray to never touch my data.